# Properties of Determinants in True or False Questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

These are some good practice problems for anyone searching on the Web for determinants problems.

There is one or two questions that I am not getting right according to the system. Could you help me find which one? Ideally, I would like you to identify which one. Then, I would like to try to give my reasoning as to why I did it wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your answer to 8 is incorrect.  This has little to do with your grasp of the material and everything to do with the ambiguous wording of the question.

I think that by "for all matrices $A$", they mean for arbitrary $n \times m$ matrices (that is, we are no-longer looking just at $n \times n$ matrices, only for the context of this question).

Comment: Yes! Perfect. That was it. It accepted it. Oh boy, I'll inform my TA about this. Totally tricky!

Comment: Of course, because determinants is a concept defined only for nxn matrices.

Comment: Yes, you got it.  My guess is that whoever made these questions wasn't paying attention